# command input splits after each letter python remote control program

Tags: sockets, client-server, python-3.3

I am working on a backdoor program for remote operations over my PC's at home. The server connects fine but I have a problem in executing the commands as the letters split up as a new command for each alphabet typed...
Something like when I type 'echo', the results print something as 'e' is not recognized as an internal or external command and blah blah.
then comes: 'c' is not recognized etc. etc.

Got my point???

How do I make this work that when I type echo it waits for the complete command

Here is the code:

```
import socket
import subprocess
s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((ipadd_of_pc_running_this_appl,12345))
s.listen(3) #ignore this plz..i will change this later
cli,addr=s.accept()
while 1:
    data=cli.recv(1024)
    if data:
        data=data.decode() #string type conversion
        proc=subprocess.Popen(data,shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        output=proc.stdout.readline()+proc.stderr.readline()
        cli.send(output)
```

Btw I want to use telent or similar to connect to it plz
thanks in advance
sorry about the recv_into...i forgot to change it recv thanks

**NOTE: The problem isn't solved yet. I copied and pasted content from my other file [minute changes ;)]. Now the  code is edited. Kindly help me out**

Comment: remove `stderr=subprocess.PIPE` so stderr goes into stdout -> better readability if errors and output mix.

Comment: how is it you are not passing a buffer to `recv_into`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trail-and-errors, I have found the solution

The line `data =cli.recv(1024)` changes to `data =cli.recv(2048)`

I do not know why but it worked :D

Answer (score 0):

Popen expects a list of arguments, so try this:

```
 Popen([data],
```

Answer (score 0):

I could get this to work by changing

```
data=cli.recv_into(1024)
```

to

```
data=cli.recv(1024)
```

`recv_into` expects a buffer parameter, I have no idea how the OP's code is not throwing a failure.

Here is the code

```
import socket
import subprocess
s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(('127.0.0.1',12345))
s.listen(1) #ignore this plz..i will change this later
cli,addr=s.accept()
while 1:
      data =cli.recv(1024)
      if data:
              data=data.decode() #string type conversion
              proc=subprocess.Popen(data,shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
              output=proc.stdout.readline()+proc.stderr.readline()
              print(output)
```

Comment: my friend sorry but its recv not recv_into...sorry my bad

Comment: @suryatejakarra, if it works for you feel free to accept answer

Comment: no my friend, my problem is not this...its the telnet client of windows which is causing the problem...i tried connecting with the same server using ubuntu and had telnet to it...the server waits until i hit return and then proceeds...i tried it using android terminal emulator too [dnt ask i have a rooted android mobile]...the telnet client of my windows 7 is the culprit...